# Get directory of an executable using which

Tags: linux, bash, zsh

I would like to use the which command to cd directly into a directory.

`cd $(which python3.6)`

Obviously this will not work, since `which python3.6` will return an executable.

Now the question is: how can I cd into the location of this executable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`dirname`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dirname):

```
cd `dirname $(which python3.6)`
```

***From [man(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dirname) page:***

> ***Name:***
>   `dirname` - strip non-directory suffix from file name
>
> ***Synopsis:***
>   `dirname NAME`
>   `dirname OPTION`
>
> ***Description:***
>   Print `NAME` with its trailing /component removed; if `NAME` contains no
>   /'s, output '.' (meaning the current directory).

Comment: Life can be easy. Thanks

Comment: @JohanVergeer, Glad to help :)

Answer (score 4):

Presuming you're using Zsh as tagged, you can use some short notation
to get there:

```
cd =python3.6(:h)
```

The `=` expansion is essentially a shortcut for `which`.  The `:h` is
to take the *"head"* of the path, thus equivalent to `dirname`.  See
`man zshexpn` for details on the `:h` modifier and others.